# How to use would have+past participle in sentences?

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the usage of (would have +pp)

I've come across lots of sentences like these:

we’d rather do something else with the money we would have spent on a reception!

I would have felt a bit shameful about getting married even though it wasn’t what I wanted.

Wouldn't they have called your father to tell you it's closed by now?

She would have said no whatever we picked.

Iv'e been looking for it's usage for a while but all my attempts are in vain.
So could you please tell me how do you use  this tense as native speakers?

Thanks

Comment: That question is too broad. The form is used for counterfactual conditionals.

Comment: Please define what you mean by *pp*. (It's far better to actually spell it out in the title and body of your question.)

Comment: I mean with pp ,the past participle